# button.setText() and Thread.sleep()

Tags: android, multithreading, settext, thread-sleep

Noob question on its way. In the code below I update text of a button in Android. Then I want to wait two seconds and then update the text again. If I comment the second b.setText("Send data"), the one after the sleep - then b.setText("Success") is written to the button. If I do not comment that one I will never see text "Success" on the button, only "Send data". It's like the Thread.sleep() is skipped when I have the second b.setText("Send data"). Google suggested to add a timer after setText("Success") so that setText() code would have time to be execited before the sleep. Did not help.

```
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            b.setText("Send data");

            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               b.setClickable(false);
               b.setText("Success");
               System.out.println("Debug before");

               try
               {
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {

               }

               System.out.println("Debug after");
               b.setText("Send data");
               b.setClickable(true);
    }
    });
```

Comment: You block your render loop.

Comment: You have to spawn a new thread that will do the update. So instead of waiting in the main thread, spawn a new thread which contains your thread.sleep() and the update.

Comment: Thanks! I tried some version of that but then I got the error that updates only can be done by the thread that created the button, and that is the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

Don't block your main thread. Use Handler.post instead

```
           b.setClickable(false);
           b.setText("Success");
           System.out.println("Debug before");

           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
               System.out.println("Debug after");
               b.setText("Send data");
               b.setClickable(true);
           }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.
you can run a new thread and then update view.

Or :

```
     CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 //
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                   //update your view
                   System.out.println("Debug after");
                   b.setText("Send data");
                }
            };
            countDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!